# SQL removing spaces, non-numeric and second character from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have the following column in my table

```
MobilePhone
----------
+1 647 555 5556
```

I want to end up with the following format.

Basically removing the '+' sign, the country code '1' and all spaces.

```
MobilePhone
----------
6475555556
```

can someone please point to right direction.

Comment: Is the country code always 1 character long?

Comment: [`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) function

Comment: Try to learn about `SUBSTRING` & `REPLACE` functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're all US phone numbers, you could try:

```
select RIGHT(REPLACE(MobilePhone,' ',''),10)
From table
```

Comment: Thanks LONG, Siyual... that did it!

Answer (score 1):

Read past the first space, remove other spaces:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MobilePhone, CHARINDEX(' ', MobilePhone, 1), LEN(MobilePhone)), ' ', '')
```

This assumes your format is strict, if it can be any country code with optional spaces you need another lookup table as they are variable length.

Comment: That's a better answer than the one I provided. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I've nested 2 operations in one `UPDATE` command. Innermost `REPLACE` gets rid of the spaces. The `RIGHT` leaves only 10 characters, that should remove the country code prefix (considering it's US only).

```
update tbl set MobilePhone= RIGHT(REPLACE(MobilePhone, ' ', ''),10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(REPLACE(MobilePhone,' ',''), '+','')
From table
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the right and replace function. Irrespective of the country code:
Try running this:

```
declare @a varchar(30) = '+1 510 999 1234'
declare @b varchar(30) = '+91 98318 12345'

SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(@a,' ',''),10) --5109991234
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(@b,' ',''),10) --9831812345
```